# How to submit a HTML form to 2 places = Java Script and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I would like to submit this information to my offline Javascript database, then to my online php mysql database.  How would I have one form do both?

These are my external files:
offlinetables.js
onlinetables.php

```
<form id="mycontact">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your details</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <label for="username">Name</label>
                <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="First and last name">
                <input type="hidden" id="id"/>
            </li>

        </ol>
    </fieldset>
    <button id="submitButton" type="submit">SAVE</button>
</form><br />
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of how client-side and server-side code works. You can't include a PHP file in a `<script>` tag like that and have it update your database. Including a PHP file in a `<script>` tag makes that client-side code, even though you're using PHP to output that code.

Comment: You are right!  I edited it.

Comment: You're still not understanding it right. The PHP code you have there (besides not even being valid code) will only execute once when the original page loads. It does not execute again after you have filled out the form. You have to submit another request to the server for that. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Answer (score 1):

After you finish running your script you could submit the form using Javascript.

```
function(){
    //your code here
    document.getElementById('mycontact').submit();
}
```

JQuery: `$('#mycontact').submit();`

You will need to add the `action` attribute to your form to tell where to submit your form to (your PHP file).

You will have to change your buttons from `type=submit` to something like `type=button` in order to override the submit function with an event listener for that button.

Comment: <form id="mycontact" action="onlinetables.php">, then in onlinetables.php run the function?

Comment: In your onlinetables.php have the PHP code that will do what you want with the form data. The form data will get passed when your Javascript does the `.submit()` function on your form and your PHP code will process it.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery combined with the FormData object:

```
$("#my-form").submit(  function (eForm) {


    eForm.preventDefault();
    var form_dat = new FormData(this);

 $.ajax ({

    type: "POST",
    url: "formserver.php",
    mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
    data: form_dat, 
    cache: false, 
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    success: sucFunc



})  

})
```

You can then chain the functions to do as many submits as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FormData javascript object to do an AJAX submit in the form's onsubmit call. Have your form setup to submit to php normally and then add the javascript handling. Without getting into too many specifics, try something like this.

```
document.getElementById('mycontact').onsubmit = function(){
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    var url = "example.php";    //your url here
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
};
```

By not returning `false` or doing `event.preventDefault();`, the form should submit as normal.